# addeventlistener on button does not retrieve the latest values of text inputs

Tags: javascript

I have a form that contains 4 fieldsets, each fieldset has text inputs and a button that will send a POST request with the data of the corresponding fieldset only.

The submit action works as expected but it always send the initial values of text inputs, even if the values have changed (see the code snippet).

I also tried to create a variable for a given fieldset element before adding the eventlistener but the console.log was still displaying the initial values and not the new values...

EDIT : the code below shows the log of `.elements` as an example, but the goal was to get names & values of inputs to send them in a `POST` request.

```js
const ready = (e) => {
  let form = document.querySelector('#test-form');

  form.querySelectorAll('button[name="btn-submit"]').forEach((el) => {
    el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      
      console.log([...el.closest('fieldset').elements]);
    });
  });
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready);
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <form id="test-form">
      <fieldset for="test-form">
        <input type="text" value="initial value" name="input-test-1" />
        <button type="submit" name="btn-submit">Submit 1</button>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset for="test-form">
        <input type="text" value="" name="input-test-2" />
        <button type="submit" name="btn-submit">Submit 2</button>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset for="test-form">
        <input type="text" value="" name="input-test-3" />
        <button type="submit" name="btn-submit">Submit 3</button>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset for="test-form">
        <input type="text" value="" name="input-test-4" />
        <button type="submit" name="btn-submit">Submit 4</button>
      </fieldset>
      <button type="submit" name="btn-main-submit">Other submit</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to demonstrate.  The code shown never reads the *value* from any input, it just logs the *element itself* to the console.  Are you looking for the `.value` property?

Comment: Updating an input doesn't change the HTML mark-up, the updated values won't be reflected in the data when you log out `.elements`. Is that what you are expecting?

Comment: @David yes I was looking for the names & values but I always got the original values. Heretic Monkey's trick works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `console.log` on HTML Elements merely shows the original HTML representation of the element. If you want the current values of its properties (not its original attributes), you need to amend your code to log the property(ies) you want:

Here I'm using the overload of [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) that takes a mapping function.

```js
const ready = (e) => {
  let form = document.querySelector('#test-form');

  form.querySelectorAll('button[name="btn-submit"]').forEach((el) => {
    el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      
      console.log(Array.from(el.closest('fieldset').elements, (el) => el.value));
    });
  });
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready);
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <form id="test-form">
      <fieldset for="test-form">
        <input type="text" value="initial value" name="input-test-1" />
        <button type="submit" name="btn-submit">Submit 1</button>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset for="test-form">
        <input type="text" value="" name="input-test-2" />
        <button type="submit" name="btn-submit">Submit 2</button>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset for="test-form">
        <input type="text" value="" name="input-test-3" />
        <button type="submit" name="btn-submit">Submit 3</button>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset for="test-form">
        <input type="text" value="" name="input-test-4" />
        <button type="submit" name="btn-submit">Submit 4</button>
      </fieldset>
      <button type="submit" name="btn-main-submit">Other submit</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes @Heretic Monkey that's what I wanted, thanks. I did not know the trick.